# How to Update a Rails 4 Form Input with methods and Regex

Tags: regex, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently making a URL shortener in Rails. The user can enter both the given_url and then also the slug they desire. I already have some http validation on given_url area using jquery validate, but I'd like to the preferred slug to be have no characters and whitespace.

I found the correct regex/whitespace and tested it in the console, so this works!

```
  @slug_regex = slug.downcase.strip.gsub(' ', '-').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '')
```

However, I'm not sure how to enter this into my overall Rails App. I attempted to do the validates on the links model, which slug is a column, but I don't want to just validate the correctness of it... I want to automatically update it.

I attempted to make a before_save private method in the links controller.  Here is where i ended up this.  It does not work.  The error says :

```
NameError (uninitialized constant LinksController::Slug):
app/controllers/links_controller.rb:40:in `before_save'

class LinksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_link, only: [:show]
  before_action :before_save

  def show
    if params[:slug]
      if redirect_to @link.given_url
        @link.save
      end
    else
      @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    end
  end

  def new
    @link = Link.new
  end

  def create
    @link = Link.new(link_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Link was successfully created.' }
        format.js {}
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @link }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.js {render file: 'links/errors.js.erb'}
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_link
      @link = Link.find_by(slug: params[:slug])
    end

    def before_save
      slug = Slug.find_by(slug: params[:slug])
      @slug_regex = slug.downcase.strip.gsub(' ', '-').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '')
    end

    def link_params
      params.require(:link).permit(:given_url, :slug)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Added a method to the model and called it before_save.

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :format_slug

  validates :given_url, presence: true

  validates :slug, uniqueness: true
  validates :slug, presence: true


  def display_slug
    ENV['BASE_URL'] + self.slug
  end

  private

    def format_slug  
      self.slug = slug.downcase.strip.gsub(' ', '-').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '')
    end

end
```